# Why when I change a image format it messes up my site

Tags: html, css, media-queries, formats

Ok this is an odd one. I've fixed it but I want to understand why it didn't work. You will have to make the screen smaller as I fixed it by putting a max-height of 255px on the li tags you can take this off if you wish when full screen and will show the same problem.

so here is the first link.

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/portfolio.html

If you look at it smaller or take off the max height it breaks, and doesn't let anything below it float there. notice that the first li img tag has a jpg for the background.

Now for this weird fix :S

I changed the JPG to a PNG and that is all I did.. and it worked
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/myWork.html

I don't have any understanding in why it would do this.. and would love someone to explain why changing a format would do something like this as to me it shouldn't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an interesting problem resulting from a small difference in maths.

If you look at your website in Firefox and you inspect the `<li class="corners hide">` element, in the portfolio page, the height computes to be 214.933px, and in the myWork page this value computes to be 210.663px.  All the other `<li class="corners">` elements evaluate to a height of 210.633 on both pages.  As a result, because of how floats work, the slightly taller first float forces the next float to start at its right edge instead of the edge of the parent container.

**But Why?**

If you look at your jpg, the dimensions are 250x261, and for the png, 250x260, 1px in height taller, that is probably the origin of the maths.  All your other background images are 250x260.  The maths difference results from using `auto` to scale the images, a bit tricky.

**How to fix it?**

Try removing the extra pixel.

Comment: +1 for a good descriptive answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a good one! All the best!

Comment: Thank, that seems to be why, I didn't think to look at the height of the bg image as it is 100% width and height is set to auto. So thought it would just fit to what ever the other LI tags were. Any ideas if I wanted to have an image that was bigger than 250x260 how to make it fit no matter what dimension? I guess you would use max height and max width but wouldn't work for how it is responsive. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your very welcome, you are using fairly advanced CSS concepts so it was good fun to work out the problem.  Your question about the 250x260 image would take some thought, will keep it in mind. If I come up with anything, I will update my post and ping you.  All the best!